# Vaue of Irrational Indefinite Integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \int\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}~~dx$

Try: Let $\displaystyle I =\int\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^2+1}}~~dx$

Put $x=\tan \theta$ and $dx=\sec^2\theta ~~d\theta$

So  $\displaystyle I =\int \sqrt{\sec \theta+\tan^2\theta}\cdot \sec^2 \theta ~~d\theta$

Using By parts, We have

$\displaystyle I =\sqrt{\sec \theta+\tan^2\theta}\cdot \tan \theta-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec \theta \tan \theta+2\tan \theta \sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{\sec \theta +\tan^2 \theta}}\cdot \tan \theta ~~d\theta$

Could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Comment: "Finding value of $\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx$" does not mean anything. An indefinite integral leads to a function, not to a number ("*value*").

Comment: yes JackD'Aurizio Right. Can you please explain how can i write in Non elementry form. Thanks

Comment: It is an elliptic integral of the third kind, which is probably not really informative, but brings us to the point: *why* are you interested in such (apparently random) integral?